# How can I take advantage of lookup tables in my Blinn-Phong lighting shader?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl

I'm experimenting with some lighting techniques on iOS and I've been able to produce some effects that I'm pleased with by taking advantage of iOS' OpenGL ES extensions for depth lookup textures and a relatively simple Blinn-Phong shader:

[image: 20 Suzanne monkeys from Blender]

The above shows 20 Suzanne monkeys being rendered at full-screen retina with multi-sampling and the following shader. I'm doing multi-sampling because it is only adding 1ms per frame. My current average render time is 30ms total (iPad 3), which is far too slow for 60fps.

Vertex shader:

```
//Position
uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 depthMVPMatrix;
uniform mat4 vpMatrix;

//Shadow out
varying vec3 ShadowCoord;

//Lighting
attribute vec3 normal;
varying vec3 normalOut;

uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
varying vec3 vertPos;
uniform vec4 lightColor;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * position;
    //Used for handling shadows
    ShadowCoord = (depthMVPMatrix * position).xyz;
    ShadowCoord.z -= 0.01;
    //Lighting calculations
    normalOut = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
    vec4 vertPos4 = vpMatrix * position;
    vertPos = vertPos4.xyz / vertPos4.w;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#extension GL_EXT_shadow_samplers : enable
precision lowp float;

uniform sampler2DShadow shadowTexture;
varying vec3 normalOut;

uniform vec3 lightPosition;
varying vec3 vertPos;

varying vec3 ShadowCoord;
uniform vec4 fillColor;
uniform vec3 specColor;

void main() {
    vec3 normal = normalize(normalOut);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPosition - vertPos);

    float lambertian = max(dot(lightDir,normal), 0.0);

    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(-vertPos);

    float specAngle = max(dot(reflectDir, viewDir), 0.0);"
    float specular = pow(specAngle, 16.0);

    gl_FragColor = vec4((lambertian * fillColor.xyz + specular * specColor) * shadow2DEXT(shadowTexture, ShadowCoord), fillColor.w);
}
```

I've [read that it is possible to use textures as lookup tables](http://aras-p.info/blog/2011/02/01/ios-shader-tricks-or-its-2001-all-over-again/) to reduce computation in the fragment shader, however the linked example seems to be doing full Phong lighting, rather than Blinn-Phong (I'm not doing anything with surface tangents). Furthermore, when running the sample the lighting seemed fairly banded (the background on mine, which is a solid color + Phong shading, looks slightly banded as a result of compression - it looks far smoother on the device). Is it possible to use a lookup texture in my case, or am I going to have to move down to 30fps (which I can just about achieve), turn off multi-sampling and limit Phong shading to the monkeys, rather than the full screen? In a real world (i.e. game) scenario, am I going to need do be doing Phong shading across the entire screen anyway?

Comment: Have you verified that it's the Phong shading slowing you down here? If you replace that with putting out a flat color, what does that do to your frame rendering times? In my experience, I've seen little performance gain when swapping dependent texture reads (for lookups) vs. more computationally expensive lighting calculations in more modern devices. Aras' work was done on an iPhone 3GS, and I'm not sure the same techniques provide as great an advantage on post-A4 GPUs.

Comment: I did some more research into this and managed to work out what was slowing it down - it was a mixture of Phong shading and the depth texture lookups for the shadows. I did also adapt the Phong calculations slightly (removed the reflect call and adapted it to be more similar to Aras' original) which I created a lookup table for and reduced frame times by about 10ms, but on the basis that I won't need to check for shadows or do Phong shading on every multi-sampled pixel at 2048*1536 at 60fps I'm going to remove the lookup table!